# ActionBar Not Showing Icons, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I recently moved from eclipse to android studio.
while importing my project to android studio, i faced a problem with action bar icons not being displayed when running on my galaxy s3.

this is the xml code

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".StartingNowHere">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:title="@string/Share"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ShopCart"
        android:icon="@drawable/shopping"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/MyCart"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/GoHome"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/nowhome"/>

</menu>
```

when using the preview option in the android studio, i can see those 3 item displayed on the virtual preview device.

[image]

this is the java part of the code, in this code i made a Toast to see if it gets processed
and it did .

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

note: this code as it is works fine on eclipse, when i imported the project into android studio, the action bar icons stopped showing .

Comment: actually still no, haven't figured out the problem yet, if i start a new project i can show action bar icons easily and set them to do what i need, however with this imported project i made the same code but still no success.

Comment: okay I got something. If we are using Theme.Holo or Theme.Holo.something, then we cannot get action icons on Actionbar. But if we use Theme.AppCompat, then it is displayed. But no idea why is this.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. I just ignore Android Studio's red line and keep it as android:showAsAction="ifRoom". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

with:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: In android Studio, it forces the change from android:showAsAction to app:showAsAction ...